# ACF Date fileds to Age Convert

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display Differnet Age from Advanced Custom Field. But, it's displaying total age by splitting Days, years, months etc. Actually, I want to Calculate Separately. Example:
I want to display as-

> 28 years | 343 months | 10444 Total days | 250,632 hours | 15,037,920
>   minutes | 15,037,920 seconds

I tried using this code, but not working.

```
<?php
 $date = get_field('dob'); 
 $birthday = new DateTime($date);
 $interval = $birthday->diff(new DateTime);
    echo $interval->days.'Total days'."\n";
    echo $interval->y.' years'."\n";
    echo $interval->m.' months'."\n";
    echo $interval->d.' days'."\n";
    echo $interval->h.' hours'."\n";
    echo $interval->i.' minutes'."\n";
    echo $interval->s.' seconds'."\n";  
?>
```

It's displaying-

> 10444 Total days 28 years 7 months 2 days 0 hours 4 minutes 32 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$birthday_ts = strtotime( get_field('dob') );
$now         = current_time( 'timestamp' );
$years       = intval( ( $now - $birthday_ts ) / YEAR_IN_SECONDS );
$months      = intval( ( $now - $birthday_ts ) / MONTH_IN_SECONDS );
$weeks       = intval( ( $now - $birthday_ts ) / WEEK_IN_SECONDS );
$days        = intval( ( $now - $birthday_ts ) / DAY_IN_SECONDS );
$hours       = intval( ( $now - $birthday_ts ) / HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
$minutes     = intval( ( $now - $birthday_ts ) / MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
$seconds     = intval( ( $now - $birthday_ts ) );

echo $years . ' years | ' . $months . ' months | ' . $weeks . ' weeks | ' . $days . ' days | ' . $hours . ' hours | ' . $minutes . ' minutes | ' . $seconds . ' seconds' ;
```

I just tried it with my own birth date, 16-08-1978 and got this result:

```
39 years | 481 months | 2061 weeks | 14433 days | 346394 hours | 20783654 minutes | 1247019262 seconds
```

Comment: You just made my Day, Beee. Problem Solved. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Can u do me a favour and mark my answer as accepted ? (click the check mark below the arrows).